# Focusing a client by indicating its direction from the currently focused client

Tags: awesome

Using the awesome window manager (version 3.5.6), I'm looking for a way to move may focus to the left/right/up/down relative to my currently focused client. For instance, given this layout:

```
+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |
|  A  |  B  |  C  |
|     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

If the focus is on client A, I'd like a keyboard shortcut that moved the focus to client B. Pressing it again would focus on client C and pressing it another time would do nothing. Other shortcuts would move to the right, up or down.

I know how to bind commands to keyboard shortcuts in my `rc.lua` but not which command I could use here, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: By "view" I assume you mean "client"?

Comment: Yes, thanks for mentioning it. I've updated the lingo in my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are looking for `awful.client.focus.by_direction`.

https://awesomewm.org/apidoc/classes/client.html#awful.client.focus.bydirection

For example:

```
# dir The direction, can be either "up", "down", "left" or "right". 
awful.key({ modkey,           }, "j", function ()
    awful.client.focus.bydirection("down")                        
end)
```